# Alternative designs for the login "remember me" checkbox?

Tags: forms, login, remember-me

I've been conducting some research on the "remember me" feature commonly found on website login pages.

[image]

Does anyone have any examples of alternative methods to implement the "remember me" feature other than using a checkbox?

Answer (score 4):

Show modal after succesfully login to ask user if they want to keep logged in

[image: modal new login session]

or take for example from vk.com, they use the checkbox but do the opposite way from remember me

[image: vk.com login form]

Answer (score 0):

Remember me on mobile is so 2010. Google and Apple take care of remembering passwords on their devices. You can just ignore the flow on the app, which will be realised by the OS.

Comment: This is not a mobile application, and I am absolutely insistent on there being a "remember me" feature. Do you have any non-checkbox ideas on how to implement this?